# Delete a polygon from a map with more polygons

Tags: google-maps

I've found similar question here but the answer was only for the insertion part, not deleting a polygon in a map with more polygons inside that is my specific question.

My code initializes the map loading a list of polygons an inserting then in a google map, something like:

```
(in a loop) {
  var poly=getNextPolygon();
  poly.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function() {
    //insert code to delete only this polygon from the map hera
  });
}
```

My code works ok for loading and drawing polygons, and answering to a click inside each polygon.

So I load for example, 3 polygons and when I click inside one of them I would like the map to reload without this polygon, can somebody tell me the code inside the listener? I'm new to google maps coding sorry if it's a silly question.

Regards.

Comment: Need more context if you want the polygon to be deleted permanently.  If you just want to "hide" it this time, we can tell you that (poly.setMap(null)).

Comment: This [example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r282/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html) allows you to click on a polygon (or any object) and delete it.